# Unable to import a library into VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed *pywhatkit*, and it's stored along with other packages in my python3.8 file. However, I am not able to import it to VS code or any other IDEs. I tried installing tkinter. But I facing the same issue again. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes VS Code does this. You should **install a library**, after that just **restart VS Code** and the problem should be **solved**.
However, if the problem still occurs, it will be due to the **Python version**.

You are using **Python 3**, the issue is most likely that when you installed ***pywhatkit*** and ***tkinter*** you used the **`pip install` *`library`*** command, which will only install them for **Python 2**. To install the libraries for **Python 3** just use the **`pip3 install` *`library`*** command in place of **pip**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the right python interpreter. The Status Bar always shows the current interpreter:

[image]

Inspect whether you can find the packages you want to import in this environment.

Inspect where the packages you have installed through pip: `pip show xxx`.